# What is the exact definition of a closure?

Tags: functional-programming, closures

I've read through previous topics on closures on stackflow and other sources and one thing is still confusing me.  From what I've been able to piece together technically a closure is simply the set of data containing the code of a function and the value of **bound variables** in that function.

In other words technically the following C function should be a closure from my understanding:

```
int count()
{
    static int x = 0;

    return x++;
}
```

Yet everything I read seems to imply closures must somehow involve passing functions as first class objects.   In addition it usually seems to be implied that closures are not part of procedural programming.  Is this a case of a solution being overly associated with the problem it solves or am I misunderstanding the exact definition?

Comment: Wikipedia is particularly good at definitions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29

Comment: However, Wikipedia definitions like this tend to be written by pipe-stress freaks and crystallography weenies (i.e. they aren't always the easiest birds to understand).

Comment: The wikipedia article was one that I read.  It says that any first class function with free variables is a closure.  That doesn't make any sense though because that includes all first class functions which return values based on their arguments.  Is it implying that it becomes a closure when the function uses free variables to instantiate it's bound variables?

Comment: Well, a C function isn't first class, obviously.

Comment: Yes but I thought the wiki definition was wrong.  I see now that my entire problem resolved around the fact that "free variables" in computer science are not the same as they are in mathematics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand a closure also has to have access to the variables in the calling context.  Closures are usually associated with functional programming.  Languages can have elements from different types of programming perspectives, functional, procedural, imperative, declarative, etc.  They get their name from being closed over a specified context.  They may also have lexical binding in that they can reference the specified context with the same names that are used in that context.  Your example has no reference to any other context but a global static one.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))

A closure closes over the free variables (variables which are not local variables)

Comment: Even if it doesn't use those variables?  In other words a closure would have to keep it's own copy of every accessible global in case that global changed?

Comment: The closure have access to the variable in the *defined* context, not the *calling* context. In theory, you can define a closures in a scope and access in another hence giving a way bypassing the scope rules -- although not all programming language allow this.

Comment: @Amaron: Not "it's own copy" -- it's the same copy. If you modify one, you modify the another.  (Again, not all programming language allow this, but this is how closure defined)

Comment: Hmmm so if it were a closure it would store pointers to all globals in it's defined context?

Comment: "A closure closes over the free variables (variables which are not local variables)" I think this finally made me understand.  That's not what wikipedia says by the way but it should.  I was getting confused because every example given shows free variables that go out of scope and thus become dereferenced outside the function and hence in mathematical terms cease to be free variables.

Comment: Most of these languages are lexically scoped, so where a variable is "in scope" depends on the syntax, not the runtime behavior. Dynamically, that means with good closure support, variables can be in scope at one point, out of scope the next, and then back in scope.

Answer (score 23):

No, that's not a closure. Your example is simply a function that returns the result of incrementing a static variable.

Here's how a closure would work:

```
function makeCounter( int x )
{
  return int counter() {
    return x++;
  }
}

c = makeCounter( 3 );
printf( "%d" c() ); => 4
printf( "%d" c() ); => 5
d = makeCounter( 0 );
printf( "%d" d() ); => 1
printf( "%d" c() ); => 6
```

In other words, different invocations of makeCounter() produce different functions with their own binding of variables in their lexical environment that they have "closed over".

Edit: I think examples like this make closures easier to understand than definitions, but if you want a definition I'd say, "A closure is a combination of a function and an environment. The environment contains the variables that are defined in the function as well as those that are visible to the function when it was created. These variables must remain available to the function as long as the function exists."

Comment: That is indeed a closure but I was looking for the exact strict definition of what is and isn't a closure.  The example I gave was meant to imply something that I thought should be a closure but I knew probably was not a closure.  Still I'll upvote you for a clear and useful example that doesn't involve lisp.

Answer (score 12):

For the [exact definition, I suggest looking at its Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). It's especially good. I just want to clarify it with an example.

Assume this C# code snippet (that's supposed to perform an `AND` search in a list):

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "hello world", "goodbye world" };
IEnumerable<string> filteredList = list;
var keywords = new [] { "hello", "world" };
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    filteredList = filteredList.Where(item => item.Contains(keyword));

foreach (var s in filteredList)  // closure is called here
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

It's a common pitfall in C# to do something like that. If you look at the lambda expression inside `Where`, you'll see that it defines a function that it's behavior depends on the value of a variable at its definition site. It's like passing a *variable itself* to the function, rather than the *value of that variable*. Effectively, when this closure is called, it retrieves the value of `keyword` variable at that time. The result of this sample is very interesting. It prints out **both** "hello world" and "goodbye world", which is not what we wanted. What happened? As I said above, the function we declared with the lambda expression is **a closure over `keyword` *variable*** so this is what happens:

```
filteredList = filteredList.Where(item => item.Contains(keyword))
                           .Where(item => item.Contains(keyword));
```

and at the time of closure execution, `keyword` has the value "world," so we're basically filtering the list a couple times with the same keyword. The solution is:

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords) {
    var temporaryVariable = keyword;
    filteredList = filteredList.Where(item => item.Contains(temporaryVariable));
}
```

Since `temporaryVariable` is scoped to the **body** of the `foreach` loop, in every iteration, it is a different variable. In effect, each closure will bind to a distinct variable (those are different instances of `temporaryVariable` at each iteration). This time, it'll give the correct results ("hello world"):

```
filteredList = filteredList.Where(item => item.Contains(temporaryVariable_1))
                           .Where(item => item.Contains(temporaryVariable_2));
```

in which `temporaryVariable_1` has the value of "hello" and `temporaryVariable_2` has the value "world" at the time of closure execution.

Note that the closures have caused an extension to the lifetime of variables (their life were supposed to end after each iteration of the loop). This is also an important side effect of closures.

Comment: As of .NET Framework v4.5.2 the first code snippet only writes out hello world. The filteredList is a {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<string>} after the first foreach  loop in both code snippits and is resolved during the second foreach loop

Answer (score 3):

A closure is an implementation technique for representing procedures/functions with local state. One way to implement closures is described in SICP. I will present the gist of it, anyway.

All expressions, including functions are evaluated in an *environement*, An environment is a sequence of *frames*. A frame maps variable names to values. Each frame also has a 
pointer to it's enclosing environment. A function is evaluated in a new environment with a frame containing bindings for it's arguments. Now let us look at the following interesting scenario. Imagine that we have a function called *accumulator*, which when evaluated, will return another function:

```
// This is some C like language that has first class functions and closures.
function accumulator(counter) {
    return (function() { return ++counter; });
}
```

What will happen when we evaluate the following line?

```
accum1 = accumulator(0);
```

First a new environment is created and an integer object (for *counter*) is bound to 0 in it's first frame. The returned value, which is a new function, is bound in the global environment. Usually the new environment will be garbage collected once the function 
evaluation is over. Here that will not happen. *accum1* is holding a reference to it, as it needs access to the variable *counter*. When *accum1* is called, it will increment the value of *counter* in the referenced environment. Now we can call *accum1* a function with local state or a closure.

I have described a few practical uses of closures at my blog
http://vijaymathew.wordpress.com. (See the posts "Dangerous designs" and "On Message-Passing").

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of answers already, but I'll add another one anyone...

Closures aren't unique to functional languages. They occur in Pascal (and family), for instance, which has nested procedures. Standard C doesn't have them (yet), but IIRC there is a GCC extension.

The basic issue is that a nested procedure may refer to variables defined in it's parent. Furthermore, the parent may return a reference to the nested procedure to its caller.

The nested procedure still refers to variables that were local to the parent - specifically to the values those variables had when the line making the function-reference was executed - even though those variables no longer exist as the parent has exited.

The issue even occurs if the procedure is never returned from the parent - different references to the nested procedure constructed at different times may be using different past values of the same variables.

The resolution to this is that when the nested function is referenced, it is packaged up in a "closure" containing the variable values it needs for later.

A Python lambda is a simple functional-style example...

```
def parent () :
  a = "hello"
  return (lamda : a)

funcref = parent ()
print funcref ()
```

My Pythons a bit rusty, but I think that's right. The point is that the nested function (the lambda) is still referring to the value of the local variable `a` even though `parent` has exited when it is called. The function needs somewhere to preserve that value until it's needed, and that place is called a closure.

A closure is a bit like an implicit set of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! Given that one of the OOP principles of OOP is that objects has behavior as well as data, closures are a special type of object because their most important purpose is their behavior. That said, what do I mean when I talk about their "behavior?"

(A lot of this is drawn from "Groovy in Action" by Dierk Konig, which is an awesome book)

On the simplest level a close is really just some code that's wrapped up to become an androgynous object/method. It's a method because it can take params and return a value, but it's also an object in that you can pass around a reference to it.

In the words of Dierk, imagine an envelope that has a piece of paper inside. A typical object would have variables and their values written on this paper, but a closure would have a list of instructions instead. Let's say the letter says to "Give this envelope and letter to your friends."

```
In Groovy: Closure envelope = { person -> new Letter(person).send() }
addressBookOfFriends.each (envelope)
```

The closure *object* here is the value of the envelope variable and it's *use* is that it's a param to the each method.

Some details:
Scope: The scope of a closure is the data and members that can be accessed within it.
Returning from a closure: Closures often use a callback mechanism to execute and return from itself.
Arguments: If the closure needs to take only 1 param, Groovy and other langs provide a default name: "it", to make coding quicker. 
So for example in our previous example:

```
addressBookOfFriends.each (envelope) 
is the same as:
addressBookOfFriends.each { new Letter(it).send() }
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

An object is state plus function.
A closure, is function plus state.

function f is a closure when it closes over (captured) x

Answer (score 0):

I think Peter Eddy has it right, but the example could be made more interesting.  You could define *two* functions which close over a local variable, increment & decrement.  The counter would be shared between that pair of functions, and unique to them.  If you define a new pair of increment/decrement functions, they would be sharing a different counter.

Also, you don't need to pass in that initial value of x, you could let it default to zero inside the function block.  That would make it clearer that it's using a value which you no longer have normal access to otherwise.